# SpriteKit: Scaling Does Not Work Correctly

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scale, scene

I have created a Scene in `ScaleToFill` and `AspectFit`. Both doesn't work as they should that let me think, that the code might be messed up. First of all I show you the two pictures of the modes:

ScaleToFit(Bottom and a little bit of the top is white)[image: ScaleToFit(Bottom and a little bit of the top is white)]
AspectFit(Doesn't use the whole screen)
[image: AspectFit(Doesn't use the whole screen)]

And following the code I use to create the walls:

```
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    screenHeight = self.size.height
    width = screenHeight / CGFloat(fieldsX)
    print(self.size.height)
    print(self.size.width)
    calculateStartPoint()
    createPositionForWalls()
    fillScreenWithWalls()
}

func fillScreenWithWalls(){
    for(var i = 1; i <= fieldsX; i++){
        for(var j = 1; j <= fieldsY; j++){
            if(fieldArray[j-1][i-1] == 1){
                let xPos = (CGFloat(i) * width - width/2)
                let yPos = screenHeight-(width/2) - CGFloat(j) * width
                addWall(xPos, yPos: yPos)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I just scale all fieldsX so they should fit perfectly on the screen and then I add some fieldsY as I want to(I want to have 1 field free in the bottom). Another thing I don't understand is why is the fps and node counter not visible.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.ResizeFill` works somehow. I still don't understand why `.AspectFit`outputs the screenshot.